# How to compare the values of two dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

suppose we have two dictionaries

```
d1={"a":1,"b":2}
d2={"x":4,"y":2}
```

Now I want to compare only the values of both dictionaries(no matters what keys they are having).

How can I do this operation, pls suggest...

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the values to numpy array and then broadcast the `==` operator as follows:

```
import numpy as np
d1={"a":1,"b":2}
d2={"x":4,"y":2}

np.array(list(d1.values())) == np.array(list(d2.values()))
```

output:

```
array([False,  True])
```